# Custom UITableViewCell in storyboard won't load

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7.1

I'm facing a strange problem. I have an iOS 7.1 storyboard app with a `UITableViewController` using Xcode 5. I created a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and set it as the class for the cell from the IB and also added a cell identifier. The style is set to Custom as well. I haven't made any modifications to this subclass yet though. It has only the template code you get when you create a new class.

In the table view controller I have this code. Just setting the data source and the delegate methods.

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "TextFieldTableViewCell.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    TextFieldTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"hello world";

    return cell;
}
```

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I simply set a value to the `textLabel` property of the cell. Even that doesn't get shown up. I double checked the identifier, style and everything bit they are all set.

I have no idea why this isn't working. I also checked out a few online tutorials on this subject matter like [this](http://code-and-coffee.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-use-custom-uitableviewcell.html) one but I have everything as they've described.

Can anyone please tell me if I'm missing anything?

I've uploaded a test project to my Dropbox [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g4umg93215xmoax/CustomCell.zip) if you want to take a quick look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! You've overridden the layoutSubviews of TextFieldTableViewCell class, and wrote nothing inside of it.

Just remove the layoutSubviews (for now) and it will work.

Update: A better solution;

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Comment: That was indeed the issue. Thank you :)